# Find Sum Quantity for Non matching ID from the Same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For example , i have below table,

```
ID    DetailedID    ReferenceID    ItemID    Qty
01           101             80      A101    100
01           102             90      A102    200
01           103              0      A101    050
01           104              0      A109    100
02           105             81      1010    100
02           106             82      1010    100
03           107              0      1111    020
03           108             81      1010    100
03           109              0      X200    010
03           110              0      1010    020
```

Now i want Sum Quantity which ReferenceID  = 0 and ItemID IS NOT Matched according to ID wise and that Sum of Quantity i will show to add one columns and Minimum of DetailedID of that ID.

I want Output like,

```
ID    DetailedID    ReferenceID    ItemID    Qty    AddQty
01           101             80      A101    100    055   
01           102             90      A102    200    NULL
01           103              0      A101    050    NULL
01           104              0      A109    055    NULL
02           105             81      1010    100    NULL
02           106             82      1010    100    NULL
03           107              0      1111    020    030
03           108             81      1010    100    NULL
03           109              0      X200    010    NULL
03           110              0      1010    020    NULL
```

Comment: could u show the query which u have tried ?

Comment: where do u get 055 for the first row. trying to understand the logic

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] TINYINT
   ,[DetailedID] TINYINT
   ,[ReferenceID] TINYINT
   ,[ItemID] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[Qty] TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID], [DetailedID], [ReferenceID], [ItemID], [Qty])
VALUES (01, 101, 80, 'A101', 100)
      ,(01, 102, 90, 'A102', 200)
      ,(01, 103, 0, 'A101', 50)
      ,(01, 104, 0, 'A109', 55)
      ,(02, 105, 81, '1010', 100)
      ,(02, 106, 82, '1010', 100)
      ,(03, 107, 0, '1111', 20)
      ,(03, 108, 81, '1010', 100)
      ,(03, 109, 0, 'X200', 10)
      ,(03, 110, 0, '1010', 20);

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT DS.[ID]
          ,SUM(DS.[Qty]) AS [AddQty]
    FROM @DataSource DS
    WHERE DS.[ReferenceID] = 0
        AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @DataSource I WHERE I.[ItemID] = DS.[ItemID] AND I.[ReferenceID] <> 0) 
    GROUP BY DS.[ID]
), DataSourceWithMinDetailedID AS
(
    SELECT [ID]     
          ,MIN([DetailedID]) AS [MinDetailedID]
    FROM @DataSource 
    GROUP BY [ID]
)
SELECT A.*
      ,C.[AddQty]
FROM @DataSource A
LEFT JOIN  DataSourceWithMinDetailedID B
    ON A.[ID] = B.[ID]
LEFT JOIN DataSource C
    ON B.[ID] = C.[ID]
    AND A.[DetailedID] = B.[MinDetailedID];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check following [SQL CTE Select statement](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=18)
You will realize that I used [Row_Number()](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/count-and-row-number-function-for-n-of-m-rows-query.aspx) and SUM() aggregation functions with Partition By clause besides using CASE statements
I hope it is clear

```
/*
create table ItemQuantity (
ID varchar(2),
DetailedID int,
ReferenceID int,
ItemID varchar(5),
Qty int)
insert into ItemQuantity values 
('01',           101,             80      ,'A101',    100),
('01',           102,             90      ,'A102',    200),
('01',           103,              0      ,'A101',    050),
('01',           104,              0      ,'A109',    100),
('02',           105,             81      ,'1010',    100),
('02',           106 ,            82      ,'1010',    100),
('03',           107  ,            0      ,'1111',    020),
('03',           108   ,          81      ,'1010',    100),
('03',           109    ,          0      ,'X200',    010),
('03',           110     ,         0      ,'1010',    020)
*/
;with cte as (
select 
    * ,
    QtyTemp = case when ReferenceID = 0 then Qty else 0 end,
    Flag = case when exists(select * from ItemQuantity k where i.ItemID = k.ItemID and k.ReferenceID <> 0) then 1 else 0 end,
    rn = row_number() over (partition by ID order by DetailedID)
from ItemQuantity i
)
select ID, DetailedID, ReferenceID, ItemID, Qty,
AddQty = case when rn = 1 then SUM(case when ReferenceID = 0 and Flag = 0 then QtyTemp else 0 end) OVER (Partition By ID) else null end
from cte
```

One thing about your sample, you have 55 as Qty in one row in the desired output. But the sample data has 100 for that row. Please check the data and output according to that

My script procudes following output
[image]

I hope it helps,